# using Github API vs using Git command line tools

Tags: git, github

I wish to programmatically create a new branch for a user's Github repository, add a few files into that branch and create a pull request for that branch.

One way to do this is to add my bot user as a collaborator using the Github API, add a branch using the Github API and then add the files and folders I want to merge using the blob API and then create a pull request using the Github API.

A second way would be to add my bot user as a collaborator using the API but from that point onwards do everything using the regular git command line tool (`git branch` and such) automated with a bash script.

I find the second approach much easier. Are there any disadvantages to that approach? Can the command line tools really be seen as a replacement for the API for simple tasks? What about the rate limits? I plan to use this for a number of users simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with the second approach is the creation of the pull request, which has to [use the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request).

All those steps could easily be scripted in Go with [`gogithub`](https://github.com/google/go-github), which does include [creating a PR (pull request)](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/7ea4ee6d222607c11ea86e99a6f6723beeae785d/github/pulls_test.go#L106-L133).